# How can I add a new lib path without call each one on the header?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

How can I add/call a entire path with all their files inside, without call each one on the header like:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">`

Comment: https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_style/

Comment: What they mean with "String" ? Thanks a lot for the comment

Comment: sorry i am not understanding your question, a String is any combination of letters, in this case would be the URL, there are examples at the bottom

Answer (score 0):

```
function my_custom_enqueue_scripts() {
        if ($handle = opendir(get_template_directory() . '/custom-stylesheets')) {
            $i = 1;
            while (false !== ($file = readdir($handle))) {
                if ($file != "." && $file != "..") {
                    wp_register_style('custom_stylesheets_' . $i, get_template_directory_uri() . '/custom-stylesheets/' . $file);
                    $i++;
                }
            }
            closedir($handle);
        }
    }

add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_custom_enqueue_scripts');
```

Add code to a file: functions.php

Styles should be located: you_theme/custom-stylesheets/

Comment: But, in case I have for example three different stylesheets (with different names, of course), within a path named "custom-stylesheets", how can I add all these with one function? If is the function above, I don't get it.

Comment: I updated the code, on the other, in any way. If you want to connect all the styles from the catalog. To do this scan directory and connected in a loop style (the same way as in Example I).

Comment: So, I need to call each one in any way..doesn't have a way to call directly all the stylesheets from this directory? For example, I have 100 stylesheets, I need to call each one?

Comment: I updated the answer